# performSelector on a category class method

Tags: objective-c, ios, categories

I have an NSManagedObject subclass called EventEntry that is auto-generated by Xcode and I try not to touch (in case I change the model and want to re-gen). So I put any added functionality into a category called EventEntry+Extended.

One such bit of functionality is a class method called eventEntriesByUser. I have subscribed this class method to be called periodically and use performSelector to invoke it.

EventEntry+Extended.h

```
@interface EventEntry (Extended)

    + (void)eventEntriesByUser;

@end
```

EventEntry+Extended.m

```
@implementation EventEntry (Extended)

    + (void)eventEntriesByUser
    {
        trace(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

@end
```

However I get a crash when I try to do this.

```
[EventEntry performSelector:@selector(eventEntriesByUser)];
```

Error...

```
+[EventEntry eventEntriesByUser]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbda08
```

If I move this method into EventEntry it works as expected. I've also tried including EventEntry+Extended.h in the file where I call performSelector with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the target membership got turned off on the category file and that's why the methods weren't being added. I may just delete this question.